# MySQL ranking query

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
SELECT u.user_id,r.totalVotes votes,r.totalPoints rating,@row:=@row+1 rank 
FROM mismatch_user u 
LEFT JOIN ratingItems r ON u.user_id=r.uniqueName,
(SELECT @row:=0) pos 
ORDER BY votes DESC,rating DESC
```

Output:

```
user_id    votes   rating  rank
2            2      10      2
6            2      9       6
3            2      5       3
1            1      5       1
4            1      5       4
27           1      5       27
9            0      0       9
```

The ranking miserably not telling me the truth and it's basing on the user_id. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want your output based on Rank in DESC order?

Comment: Looks like Rank is equals user_id. What did you want it to be?

Comment: @NishuTayal nope. Currently, it displaying correctly. What I need them to is iterate in ASC order. So the ranking will be 1,2,3,4 ans so on... not 2,6,3....

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine I want them to be in correct way. 1,2,3 and so on...

Comment: @Mar Cejas : I think, Here Rank is used as a local variable? Or is it a table field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?

```
select r.*, @row:=@row+1 rank 
  from 
    (SELECT u.user_id,r.totalVotes votes,r.totalPoints rating
       FROM mismatch_user u 
         LEFT JOIN ratingItems r ON u.user_id=r.uniqueName
    ) r
    join (SELECT @row:=0) pos 
ORDER BY r.votes DESC, r.rating DESC
```

Comment: Great! this one works. How about if the votes and rating is NULL it will display the last rank number?

Comment: I ran a test in MySQL and the record with null was considered the smallest of all. So in your case it would be the last, yes, as your ordering it with DESC. Not sure if you should rely on that though.

Comment: By the way, I if it is NULL I need them to ORDER BY u.user_id ASC. I tried but not working. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're generating a sequence and that can lead to tricky behavior.

If your query is correct, the **safest** way to sort by rank is now to embed it in another SELECT:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT u.user_id,r.totalVotes votes,r.totalPoints rating,@row:=@row+1 rank 
    FROM mismatch_user u 
    LEFT JOIN ratingItems r ON u.user_id=r.uniqueName,
    (SELECT @row:=0) pos 
    ORDER BY votes DESC,rating DESC) T
ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: Your query is just the same as sorting the user_id to ASC. That won't solve. The query is correct but the only problem is the rank column is incorrect.